# iTunes Connect: Is my app designed to use cryptography?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

My iPhone app only uses encryption to request AdMob ads over https.

What should I answer to

> Is your app designed to use cryptography or does it contain or
>   incorporate cryptography?

If yes, what do I answer to

> Does your app meet any of the following: 
>   (a) Qualifies for one or more
>   exemptions provided under category 5 part 2 
>   (b) Use of encryption is
>   limited to encryption within the operating system (iOS or macOS) 
>   (c) Only makes call(s) over HTTPS (d) App is made available only in the
>   U.S. and/or Canada

Comment: No your fine. I've got an app on the app store using ad mob, said no to that question and it went through without a hitch

Comment: @MarkDodds Just because it "went through without a hitch" does not mean that is is compliant with U.S. export requirements.

Comment: @activity 1. Is the cryptography a hash or encryption such as AES? A hash is not considered encryption and needs no export compliance. 2. Is it only for authentication, in that case is also needs no export compliance.